# Cannot control the joints using gazebo_ros_control plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am modeling a walking robot in  `URDF`  with all the joints controlled by  `gazebo_ros_control`  plugin.
It was made based on  `rrbot` . Everything seems fine when run it in gazebo, and controller topics can be found.
While when I want to use  `rostopic pub /halobject/Rl1_position_controller/command std_msg/Float64 10` , the model has no response to it. Besides, when use  `rostopic echo /halobject/Rl1_position_controller/state`  to read the joint data, it also shows  no response to my command.
During the simulation, there is no error information about it, and my `pid` parameter is set to be 100,0.01,10. `Joint state controller` publish rate to be 20.
The topics when running is as follows:

```
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/halobject/Ll1_position_controller/command
/halobject/Ll1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Ll1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Ll1_position_controller/state
/halobject/Ll2_position_controller/command
/halobject/Ll2_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Ll2_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Ll2_position_controller/state
/halobject/Lla1_position_controller/command
/halobject/Lla1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Lla1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Lla1_position_controller/state
/halobject/Ml_position_controller/command
/halobject/Ml_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Ml_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Ml_position_controller/state
/halobject/Rl1_position_controller/command
/halobject/Rl1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Rl1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Rl1_position_controller/state
/halobject/Rl2_position_controller/command
/halobject/Rl2_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Rl2_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Rl2_position_controller/state
/halobject/Rla1_position_controller/command
/halobject/Rla1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/halobject/Rla1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/halobject/Rla1_position_controller/state
/halobject/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

If anyone else met similar problem before?
My file is here `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ew8tkluu6jw1p2e/AABILHj-hwEAzYaDBIaiGfSCa?dl=0`
first source the `devel/setup.bash` then `roslaunch halobject_gazebo halobject_world.launch` it should start working.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13462/cannot-control-the-joints-using-gazebo_ros_control-plugin/) by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pap-x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2424/pap-x/) on 2016-05-31**:
I have the same problem with a different robot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I managed to get my robot to work. I have some suggestions for you. First when you spawn the urdf in your launch file you have to spawn it with the name of your robot not **rrbot** because I think gazebo creates the controllers in the robot name namespace. In your urdf you have in every joint "effort=0.0" which is wrong, this variable defines how much torque of the motor goes to the joint. It has to be more than 0 if the joint has to move.
That's all I could suggest!

---

Originally posted by [pap-x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2424/pap-x/) with karma: 50 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on 2016-06-03**:
Thank you! I use URDF PlugIns of Solidworks to generate the URDF. I didn't set the value of torque, that's why it is zero, I will do some changes based on it.

**Comment by [wyxf007](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2601/wyxf007/) on 2016-06-03**:
Now it works, the limit is just the problem. I thought the default setting in plugin won't hurt, while ...
Thank you!

**Comment by [franklin_selva](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7905/franklin_selva/) on 2019-01-10**:
Hi. Sorry its already late for the question. I am also trying to move the joints of the biped robot. I had already set the effort values and also tuned the pid parameters. Now the robot is not collapsing but when I do 'rostopic pub joint', the joints wont move.  Can you help me with this?
Thanks in advance.